# Calling a function onkeyup innerHTML

Tags: javascript

How to call function in

```
var aviso = document.getElementById('conteudo')
        aviso.innerHTML = '<p> Favor escolher uma opção </p>'

        function alterarDados(selectObject) {
            var div = document.getElementById('conteudo')
            var value = selectObject.value
            if (value == '1') {
                div.innerHTML = '<h1> Calcular c para f </h1>'
                div.innerHTML += '<input onkeyup="calcular('+'c'+')" id="c" type="number" name="c" placeholder="insirir valor de c" ><input onkeyup="calcular('+'f'+')" id="f" type="number" name="f" placeholder="insirir valor de f" >'
            }

        }
        function cal(tipo) {
            if (tipo === 'c') {
                var c = eval(document.getElementById('c').value)
                var soma = (c*9/5) + 32
                document.getElementById('f').value = soma
                console.log(soma)
            }
            if (tipo === 'f') {
                var f = eval(document.getElementById('f').value)
                console.log(f)
                var soma = (f-32) * 5/9
                document.getElementById('c').value = soma
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code of aviso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your `onkeyup` function like

`onkeyup="calcular(\'c\')"`

Hope this works for you.

*Working Example*

```js
var aviso = document.getElementById("conteudo");
aviso.innerHTML = "<p> Favor escolher uma opção </p>";

function alterarDados(selectObject) {
  var div = document.getElementById("conteudo");
  var value = selectObject.value;
  if (value == "1") {
    div.innerHTML = "<h1> Calcular c para f </h1>";
    div.innerHTML +=
      '<input onkeyup="calcular(\'c\')" id="c" type="number" name="c" placeholder="insirir valor de c" >' 
      + '<input onkeyup="calcular(\'f\')" id="f" type="number" name="f" placeholder="insirir valor de f" >';
  }
}
function calcular(tipo) {
  console.log(tipo);
  if (tipo === "c") {
    var c = eval(document.getElementById("c").value);
    var soma = (c * 9) / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementById("f").value = soma;
    console.log(soma);
  }
  if (tipo === "f") {
    var f = eval(document.getElementById("f").value);
    console.log(f);
    var soma = ((f - 32) * 5) / 9;
    document.getElementById("c").value = soma;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo"></div>
<button onclick="alterarDados( { value: '1' })">alterarDados</button>
```